# Apache 2.4.9 on Debian 7.8 - .htaccess options not allowed

Tags: .htaccess, virtualhost, apache-2.4

I’m part the team that administrates a Apache 2.4.9 web server running on Debian 7.8. We’re having an issue with one of our users website:

**www.example.com/~user**

When we try to access this URL, a page loads with the following content:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@localhost and
>   inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log. Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at www.cpdee.ufmg.br Port 80

And in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` I find this:

```
[Fri Apr 03 11:36:36 2015] [alert] [client 179.214.195.80] /home/web/user/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
```

If I then look the content of the /home/web/user/.htacces file, there’s just this configuration line:

```
Options -Indexes
```

After a quick research, it seemed to me that this issue has to do with Apache’s virtual host configuration. Specifically, [this tutorial](http://www.binarytides.com/fix-htaccess-options-not-allowed-here-error/) says that this problem can be fixed by adding “Options” in the “AllowOverride” list of the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default, like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride FileInfo Options
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

This file is just a link to the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` file and, in my case, this file looks a little bit messy:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride Options
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride Options
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

As suggested, I added `Options` to the `AllowOverried` list (for each `<Directory> ... </Directory>` "tag" I found there). Then I enabled the changes and reloaded Apache with this set of commands:

```
a2ensite default
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Even with these changes, I still kept having the same issue and I don’t really know what’s wrong. Could someone please help me with that?

Comment: This looks OK for /var/www but are your user home directories in /var/www or something like /home/user/public_html ?

Comment: It's in /home/users/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if more specific configuration in `userdir.conf` overrides settings you specify in `<Directory />`. In `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/userdir.conf` is specified `Directory` directive for userdir, default is:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        UserDir public_html
        UserDir disabled root

        <Directory /home/*/public_html>
                AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
                Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
                <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Limit>
                <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
                        Order deny,allow
                        Deny from all
                </LimitExcept>
        </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

So you should add `Options` to the `AllowOverride` directive here.

(Probably your directory is `<Directory /home/web/*/>` instead.)

Comment: Esa, that solved my problem, thank you! And yes, my directory is `<Directory /home/web/*/>`